# Add attachment to JIRA issue with logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, jira-rest-api

The JIRA API has a method to upload attachments on [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.13.0/?_ga=2.150721136.759318290.1552430662-822074694.1549925077#api/2/issue/%7BissueIdOrKey%7D/attachments-addAttachment)
How do I do this using logic apps?

I have used the JIRA connector and selected create a new issue.  However this doesn't include a method to upload an attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pity that the `JIRA` connector cannot add attachments. From the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/jira/#create-a-new-issue), there is no such option.

[image]

Maybe you can go to the [Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) to put forward your ideas, and the development team will see it.

Comment: I've added it [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/42427627-add-attachment-to-jira)  Please can you vote for it?  Are there any workarounds eg a custom connector?

Comment: I have already voted for you. I don’t know much about custom connectors. You can ask another question and maybe someone will help you.